# Selecting only the highest value for a specific record with other unique columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have table that contains data similar to the following. The query that I need would result in the top result for Orange and Apple that has the highest cityID value.

```
id | fruit  | attr | cityID | personID 
163 Apple   green   3685    235
163 Apple   red     3145    267
163 Apple   yellow  1522    560
164 Orange  big     1344    147
164 Orange  small   833     2673
```

The results I need would be

```
id | fruit  | attr | cityID | personID 
163 Apple   green   3685    235
164 Orange  big     1344    147
```

I started trying to accomplish this with

```
select 
   fruit_id,
   fruit,
   attr, 
   max(cityID),
   personID
from fruits_cities
    group by
     fruit_id,
     fruit,
     attr, 
     max(cityID),
     personID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a challenge.  You need to use some sort of comparison.  Here is an easy way:

```
select fc.* 
from fruits_cities fc
where fc.cityId = (select max(CityId)
                   from fruits_cities fc2
                   where fc2.fruit_id = fc.fruit_id
                  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest code that may helps you.

```
SELECT fruit_id,fruit,attr,max(cityID),personID FROM `fruits_cities` GROUP BY fruit ORDER BY fruit_id
```